# How to set data in listView when got it from Retrofit request?

Tags: java, android, listview, retrofit2, adapter

I have a request with Retrofit in java android and get my data as ListArray.
I have a listView with some items.
Please tell me how to set my data source array from Retrofit in my listView.

Comment: Can you please post [mcve] and sample JSON response you get did get from API? Currently it's hard to understand your problem. If you're a novice in Retrofit and ListView, please check this [tutorial](https://www.androidhive.info/2016/05/android-working-with-retrofit-http-library/)

Answer (score 0):

convert retrofit response to object list than assign it in a global referance.Use this list object in  getView function of listview adapter to populate listview.After every response notifydata to listview.